# timedatectl: Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, package-management, systemd, docker, timezone

**The scenario:** I'm trying to set timezone on a docker container based on Ubuntu 18.04 docker image. 
Just pull the image, updated, and installed systemd

```
> apt-get -y update
> apt-get -y install systemd
```

**The error:** *Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory*

```
> timedatectl
> timedatectl: Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

**The question:** What I'm missing?

**Note:** There is no file localtime and timezone in directory etc

```
> ls /etc/localtime 
> ls: cannot access '/etc/localtime': No such file or directory
> ls /etc/timezone 
> ls: cannot access '/etc/timezone': No such file or directory
```

I've seen [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015385/i-wish-to-configure-time-synchronisation-on-ubuntu-16-04-4-but-timedatectl-give) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907925/ubuntu-timedatectl-fails-in-docker-container) but did not resolve, because dbus is not missing in my case

```
> apt-get install dbus
> dbus is already the newest version (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1).
```

Thank you

Comment: watch this [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1015385/829702), also [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907925/ubuntu-timedatectl-fails-in-docker-container) too

Comment: thank you but did not resolve because `dbus` is not missing in my case: `dbus is already the newest version (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1).` (improved the question)

Comment: expecting the same difficulties with ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 2):

This is caused by the container not having access to the system_bus_socket on the host. You need to run your container with:

```
docker run -ti -v /run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:ro imagename /bin/bash
```

Then you'll be able to use the timedatectl command.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
docker run --privileged -ti -v /run/dbus/system_bus_socket:/run/dbus/system_bus_socket:ro imagename /bin/bash
```

Same solution Lauren suggested but has the `--privileged` flag added